# Get the public email address of a Facebook user

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get an `email address` of a `Facebook` user but I'm not able to, although their email address privacy is set to public.

This is my code:

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
data = graph.request('/search?q=' +user+'&type=user')
id =  data.items()[1][1][0]["id"]
args = {'fields' : 'id,name,email' }
profile = graph.get_object(id, **args)
print profile
```

I'm not getting any error, I get the ID and the name, but not the email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That user must grant [`permission`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email) to your app for you to read their `email address`, even in case their `email address` privacy is set to `public`.

You should use the [`Facebook Graph API Explorer`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to see if you are able to get that person email address using your app `token`.

As for the python code, I think you got it right:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
fields = {'fields' : 'id,name,email'}
profile = graph.get_object(facebook_user_id, **fields)
```

Comment: OK I tried and I can't see his info.. So I cant get persons info if he is on my friends and I can see his mail in his profile? Is there any other way?

Comment: of course not. what would you do with an email if the user did not specifically authorize you to do anything with it?

Comment: @luschn Ok youre right. somehow i decided that if i have access token that refer to my profile i have the same priviliges as in my profile.. but it doesn't make any sense. Thanks!